# How to fix spark horribly misinterpreting csv?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two csv files, one containing keywords for movies, the other containing cast and crew. The `keywords.csv` file looks like this:

```
$ head -n 3 keywords.csv
id,keywords
862,"[{'id': 931, 'name': 'jealousy'}, {'id': 4290, 'name': 'toy'}, {'id': 5202, 'name': 'boy'}, {'id': 6054, 'name': 'friendship'}, {'id': 9713, 'name': 'friends'}, {'id': 9823, 'name': 'rivalry'}, {'id': 165503, 'name': 'boy next door'}, {'id': 170722, 'name': 'new toy'}, {'id': 187065, 'name': 'toy comes to life'}]"
8844,"[{'id': 10090, 'name': 'board game'}, {'id': 10941, 'name': 'disappearance'}, {'id': 15101, 'name': ""based on children's book""}, {'id': 33467, 'name': 'new home'}, {'id': 158086, 'name': 'recluse'}, {'id': 158091, 'name': 'giant insect'}]"
```

The `credits.csv` file looks like this:

```
$ head -n 2 credits.csv
cast,crew,id
"[{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f95', 'gender': 2, 'id': 31, 'name': 'Tom Hanks', 'order': 0, 'profile_path': '/pQFoyx7rp09CJTAb932F2g8Nlho.jpg'}, {'cast_id': 15, 'character': 'Buzz Lightyear (voice)', 'credit_id': '52fe4284c3a36847f8024f99', 'gender': 2, 'id': 12898, 'name': 'Tim Allen', 'order': 1, 'profile_path': '/uX2xVf6pMmPepxnvFWyBtjexzgY.jpg'}]", 1
```

Both are properly formed csvs that `pandas` has no issues reading in. Spark reads them in like this:

```
spark.read
  .option("quote", "\"")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("keywords.csv")
  .show(2)
```

outputs:

```
+-------+--------------------+
|movieId|            keywords|
+-------+--------------------+
|    862|[{'id': 931, 'nam...|
|   8844|"[{'id': 10090, '...|
+-------+--------------------+
```

It clearly show discrepancies between the fist and second row (note the presence/absence of the `"` character. This can be fixed with a simple udf containing a string replace.

For `credits.csv` it goes horribly wrong though:

```
spark.read
  .option("quote", "\"")
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("credits.csv")
  .show(2)
```

outputs:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                cast|                crew|             movieId|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[{'cast_id': 14, ...|"[{'credit_id': '...| 'profile_path': ...|
|[{'cast_id': 1, '...|[{'credit_id': '5...|                8844|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The columns are broken...

How can I read this in properly (if possible) without breaking the columns? I'm surprised `pandas` has no issues whereas spark miserably fails.

Comment: Your sample of `credits.csv`, assuming I take the quote character at face value, only has two fields. The first field string that looks like a list containing  two dictionaries; the second field is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first file you use incorrect escape character - default one in `csv` is `\` and your file uses `"`:

```
>>> (spark.read
...   .option("escape", '"')
...   .option("header", "true")
...   .csv("keywords.csv")
...   .show(2))
...   
+----+--------------------+
|  id|            keywords|
+----+--------------------+
| 862|[{'id': 931, 'nam...|
|8844|[{'id': 10090, 'n...|
+----+--------------------+
```

In the second file (`credits.csv`) there is the same problem, and additionally number of fields in the header doesn't match the data ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839384/how-to-fix-spark-horribly-misinterpreting-csv#comment82643327_47839384) by [Kirk Broadhurst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146077/kirk-broadhurst)) It cannot be correctly loaded in Spark:

```
>>> (spark.read
...   .option("escape", '"')
...   .option("header", "true")
...   .csv("credits.csv")
...   .show(2))
...   
+--------------------+----+----+
|                cast|crew|  id|
+--------------------+----+----+
|[{'cast_id': 14, ...|   1|null|
+--------------------+----+----+
```

and Pandas alike:

```
>>> pd.read_csv("credits.csv")
                                                cast  crew  id
0  [{'cast_id': 14, 'character': 'Woody (voice)',...     1 NaN
```